# TextInputEditText not showing drawableRight icon

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I am using code bellow to display User name Input. EditText is working properly but Right side display icon is not visible.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_screen_edit_text_username_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_screen_edit_text_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/label_username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/email_icon"
            android:text="abcd@gmail.com"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I am testing this code on Nexus6p android version 6.0. Parent layout is LinearLayout.Please update if anybody facing same issue and got fix for it.

Comment: They broke something in the design support library recently. You'll need to set the relative version of that; e.g., `drawableEnd`.

Comment: thanks after adding android:drawableEnd="@mipmap/email_icon" right icon is visible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use

```
 android:drawableEnd="@mipmap/email_icon"
```

instead of

```
 android:drawableRight="@mipmap/email_icon"
```